# Store uploaded file to a created directory

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently working on a website which is developed in asp. One page allows users to send messages and upload files. The file gets uploaded and I can save it to a directory no problem. However the client requires a directory to be created for each logged in user and then to save the uploaded file to that particular directory. I have managed to created the directory using the following code.

```
if (!Directory.Exists("\\Users\\uploads " + User.Identity.Name + " " + User.Identity.GetUserId()))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory("\\Users\\uploads " + User.Identity.Name + " " + User.Identity.GetUserId());
        }
```

The directory gets created as required. However I can't seem to save the file to that particular directory. Instead it saves the file to the uploads directory. Does anyone know how I can do that. Thanks in advance

My code for saving the file

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs("\\Users\\uploads " + User.Identity.Name + " " + User.Identity.GetUserId()));
```

Comment: Do you mean that file saving to the parent directory "Upload" instead of "\\Upload\\ + username + userguid"?

Comment: @andrey.shedko Yes that's what I mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clean up the code to create the directory by introducing a variable:

```
string userDirectory = "\\Users\\uploads " + User.Identity.Name + " " + User.Identity.GetUserId();

if (!Directory.Exists(userDirectory))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(userDirectory);
}
```

And then when saving to that directory, make sure to specifiy a **filename** instead of a directory:

```
string filename = Path.Combine(userDirectory, FileUpload1.Filename);

FileUpload1.SaveAs(filename);
```

See [Don't overwrite file uploaded through FileUpload control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625304/asp-net-c-sharp-fileupload-dont-overwrite-file) to make sure you don't overwrite files having the same name.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing file name in `FileUpload1.SaveAs(...)` method. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.saveas(v=vs.110).aspx) you need to retrieve `FileUpload1.FileName`.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution:

```
string targetPath = "\\Users\\uploads " + User.Identity.Name + " " + User.Identity.GetUserId());
string filePath = Path.Combine(targetPath, Server.HtmlEncode(FileUpload1.FileName));
FileUpload1.SaveAs(filePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you must change your code to be as follow:

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("pathtodirectory" + FileUpload1.FileName));
```